# How to capture user events like play, pause, mute, unmute for Vimeo Live (Event) videos?

Tags: javascript, iframe, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I use the Vimeo Player SDK to detect user interactions with the embedded video (like play, pause, mute, unmute,...).
For normal videos, the SDK works perfectly.

But for Live Event videos, the SDK does not work. In this [link](https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/12427952387601-Player-SDK) it is stated that

> The Player SDK does not apply to live events

How can I detect those interactions for Vimeo Live Event videos?
Below is an example for the Vimeo Live Event iframe:

```
<iframe width="1000" height="315" src="https://vimeo.com/event/{EVENT_ID}/embed?muted=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```